# Pandas idiomatic way of mapping json list to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataset derived from a json input, which id like to map to a pandas dataframe. Lets say the json corresponding to individual rows of the table looks like so:

```
popo = {'foo': 3.14, 'bar': [1, 2, 3]}
```

That is, on of the keys corresponding to one of the desired columns in my table is itself a list, of a fixed length.

Loading a list of such dicts, using either pandas.DataFrame.from_dict, or pandas.io.json.json_normalize, results in a dataframe with two columns, foo and bar. In both cases, bar is of type object, with these objects being python lists.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([popo] * 10, orient='index')
```

In a perfect world, what id like is for df['bar'] to dereference into an array of shape [n, 3], so I could proceed to write things like df['bar'].sum(axis=1) efficiently and concisely.

But not only does my loading code not give this result, to my unpleasant surprise, pandas does not appear to support anything but 1d arrays as series/columns on a dataframe, so I cannot subsequently manually cast to a similar format either.

Am I missing something? It feels like this isn't a very exotic use case, so surely there is an idiomatic way of working with data structured in such a way?

EDIT: another reason the column of type object containing python lists is annoying, is that binary formats like feather are unable to deal with it. So transforming this datastructure into one that can be efficiently serialized could be considered another requirement for unlocking the typical benefits of working in idiomatic pandas.

Comment: Pandas does support 3D data in 'panels' - (that's actually where the name came from). It's now deprecated in favour of [xarrays](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Panel.html). Not sure how/if this would work for your use case.

Comment: I dont think I want 3d data in the sense of xarrays or panels though; the bulk of my dataframe is overwhelmingly 2d. Also, the multiindex paradigm doesn't seem to solve my problem; though id love to be proven wrong in a more detailed response.

Comment: I guess the most common way would be to use a DataFrame with a MultiIndex.

Comment: Reading the xarray documentation in some more detail, you might be right about it addressing my use case; ill look into it more and let you know how it works out!

Comment: @JoergVanAken: can you give an example of how to solve this with a multiIndex? I dont see how it meshes with the foo key in put into my dict; thats why I put it there. In reality there are dozens of such simple 1d series columns; and a bunch of columns which conceptually can be viewed as ndarrays; not all of the same length either.

Comment: Can you give some more example of your input data? I am sure there will be a solution.

Comment: just repeating the given dict in a list would do; and then I would consider the cleanest way to do something like df['bar'].sum(axis=1) a solution

Comment: Just so I understand, are you looking for anything more than just output: `6` in your example?

Comment: I am looking for the ability to perform operations on such datastructures in a reasonably performant and expressive manner. The number 6 has no special meaning to me; but yes in the given example the solution would be a series or array of length 10 with the value 6 repeating.

Comment: It does indeed seem like xarray supports this type of datastructure using its Dataset object. That is good to know; but sadly of not much practical use yet in the seeming absence of an equivalent of pandas.io.json.json_normalize in xarray...

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, this is the most satisfying answer I have found so far; to preprocess my json derived datastructure by casting all lists (or iterables) to enumerated dicts:

```
def list_to_dict(popo):
    if isinstance(popo, dict):
        return {k: list_to_dict(v) for k, v in popo.items()}
    try:
        return {str(i): list_to_dict(v) for i, v in enumerate(popo)}
    except:
        return popo
```

Now we have:

```
list_to_dict(popo) == {'foo': 3.14, 'bar': {'0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3}}
```

That at least allows me to write things like:

```
df = pandas.io.json.json_normalize([list_to_dict(popo)] * 10)
df[[f'bar.{i}' for i in range(3)]].sum(axis=1)
```

Not a huge fan since this preprocessing does not come for free, and also the access will not have the same efficiency as addressing a single contiguous array... but maybe ill have to settle for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't going to get you where you wanted to go, but I had fun trying, so I figured I'll share this, because why not?

```
import pandas as pd

popo = {'foo': 3.14, 'bar': [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([popo]*10)
df
```

Output:

```
        bar     foo
0   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
1   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
2   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
3   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
4   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
5   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
6   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
7   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
8   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
9   [1, 2, 3]   3.14
```

Let's define a function:

```
def obj_sum(df, column):
   new_col = []
   for i in df[column].tolist():
           new_col.append(sum(i))
   df.drop(column, axis = 1, inplace = True)
   df[column] = new_col
   return df
```

And, finally, let's what this does:

```
obj_sum(df,'bar')
```

Output:

```
    foo     bar
0   3.14    6
1   3.14    6
2   3.14    6
3   3.14    6
4   3.14    6
5   3.14    6
6   3.14    6
7   3.14    6
8   3.14    6
9   3.14    6
```

Well, at least I tried...

Comment: Thanks for sharing; indeed this isn't my preferred solution; if we are to have a loop over all rows, id want it to be as a preprocessing step, so subsequent operations can be reasonably efficient. Another requirement which I forgot to mention is that I can serialize the resulting dataframe efficiently in a binary format; and feather freaks out about the column of type object containing python lists, for instance.